# Can I move the axes of a ggplot to centre the data in R

Tags: ggplot2, axes

I am plotting meteor observation data from a sky camera, sometimes using right ascension and declination for my x and y axes, at other times azimuth and elevation. The problem I have in both cases is with the x axis when my observations span the 360 degree mark. Sometimes I get a batch of observations on the left of my plot (near zero degrees, and a batch on the right hand side (near 360 degrees), with a big expanse of nothing in the middle. Is there any easy way I can change the x axis so that the 360/0 degree wrap over is in the centre of the plot? I would still want to show the true azimuth (or right ascension) in the axis labels.
PS. Pointing the camera elsewhere is not an option [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOlzm.jpg)
PPS So in the image shown the plots on the left hand side should be to the right of those on the right hand side with x axis from 250 (via 360/0) to 100.

PPPS So the second image shows what I am after - but I got to that by doctoring the data - as is obvious from the scale of the x axis in this plot

[image]

Comment: Please can you include some sample data and a sketch of what you want. Might be possible with a transform - see `?scales::trans_new`

Comment: What about using `facet_grid()` or `facet_wrap()` to facet the data?  Basically, you would have two pictures like the second one side-by-side in the final plot.  It would remove all the empty space between about 100 and 250 RA.